# Alternative to frames with CSS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, dhtml

I am looking for a way to achieve the layout using CSS or any other method that can accommodate the design and implementation.

The "top" portion is a fixed area. The "left" area will be a list of text links that target to the "main" area. To be more specific, a list of links to profiles will be in the "left" area and I want the associated profile to show in the "main" area.

I can do it with frames, but since it is not the best way or is not supported by HTML5, I want some other alternative for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting some of your elements as `position: fixed;` in CSS. For example make a div for the top and a div for your sidebar, set those for `position: fixed;` in CSS.
Your main area div is just a normal div which will be scrolled with the normal body.

It's really easy and works on all major browser (excluding some mobile browsers I think).

No need for jQuery or Javascript. You can use things like PHP include for your main area.

**Update**
You can also make DIVs with fixed sizes and add the attribute `overflow: scroll`; to get a similar result.

Comment: +1 Though you could 'progressively enhance' with JavaScript/jQuery so that clicking on a URL on the left loads a page over AJAX and inserts it in the main area.

Comment: of course. In fact there are SEO and usability issues with the URL If you're not using url hashes and using url hashes might be too high level for him now.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this Steve Sanderson blog post:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/

Answer (score 0):

Yes ... you can use jquery and the load() function as I suppose you are using only HTML  and not serversidescripting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Frames and you don't need any reload or AJAX if you don't like to.
Put all HTML on one page.
Put your head, side and contents in different div containers.
Use style.display = "none" or style.display = "" to steer which link from the left side opens which div in the content area...

Alternatively you can get the content of the profiles using AJAX.

I don't know, if this answer is good enough for you, because I don't know about your JavaScript Knowledge.

Comment: that's poor for performance and also not good for mobile devices which additional load the invisible content. Of course this will work fine for small pages.

Comment: What part of it? The AJAX part or the inline part?
I wrote about two alternatives and asked for the knowledge of the requester.

Comment: Putting all the HTML stuff in one page and using `display: none;`